Neither "net" nor "whoami" show distribution groups
My Windows-account myUser is member of an Active Directory distribution group myGroup. I verified this via this PowerShell-command.
(Get-ADUser myUser -Properties MemberOf | select MemberOf).MemberOf `
| Get-ADGroup `
| Select -ExpandProperty Name

However neither of the following commands displays this AD-group.

whoami /groups
net user myUser /domain
net group | findstr myGroup
gpresult /r | findstr myGroup

While gpresult /r documents to only show security groups and not distribution groups, this seems to be undocumented behaviour for net.exe or whoami.exe.
Is it true that neither net nor whoami can show distribution groups? Or is another property of the group the reason it is not displayed?
I am aware that this cannot be verified for my concrete group, but I was hoping someone either knows this or could double-check with a distribution group in their network.

Yes, expected behavior.

Also this is a feature of distribution groups. There is a hard limit on the number of security groups that an account can be a member of. Distribution groups overcome that limitation.

Is there any documentation of this behaviour for whoami.exe or net.exe?

whoami specifically shows you groups that are part of the process security token. That's its purpose – it doesn't make a directory search like Get-AD does, but only dumps what its own process has at the moment.
(For example, if AD memberships were updated, your processes would still have the old token and whoami would also show the old information that was established at logon time.)
Distribution groups, by definition, are groups that don't go in the process security token – they have no SID and exist solely as LDAP objects (for use by programs that need LDAP groups without bloating the user's security token, which is of limited size, as are Kerberos tickets) – thus they are invisible to 'whoami'.
Group policies are applied using file security ACLs, so they (and gpresult) rely on the same process token as 'whoami' does.
As for net, it is a command that predates AD and is from the "WinNT domain" era, and if I remember correctly, distribution groups did not exist in NT4 domains and thus are invisible to the legacy APIs that net uses. (I think they originate from Exchange, which later evolved into AD?)
